# How to display 20 records in sqlite in Android

Tags: android, performance

I use this query in Android sqlite:

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_CODE, KEY_NAME, KEY_CITY, KEY_COUNTRY }, KEY_CODE
            + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null, null, null, null, null);
```

I want to display 20 records, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.query("table", null, "column=?", new String[]{"value"}, null, null, "id DESC", "20");
```

Here last argument 20 is the limit count for the records. it will give only 20 records if there is more than 20.

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM People
               ORDER BY _id DESC
               LIMIT 20)

Answer (score 0):

try rowQuery with LIMIT operator like this

```
db.rawQuery("select * from yourTable where filedname like '%" + inputText + "%' LIMIT 20");
```